# how to display send message on right side and recieved message on left side in nodejs using socket.io

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, socket.io

I am making a chatbox using `socket.io`. but then the problem occurs when I am trying to display the message on their respective side.

I want to display the send message on the right side and the received message on the left side.

I want as-

```
received message
received message
                  send message
received message
```

HTML file code is -

```
   <div class="panel-body">
           <ul class="chat" id="chat"></ul>
   </div>
```

My client side code is-

```
       $messageForm.click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            socket.emit('send message', $message.val());
            $message.val('');
        });

        socket.on('new message', function (data) {
                $("#chat").append('<div style="text-align: right"><strong>' + data.user + '</strong> : ' + data.msg + '</div>').scrollTop(1E10);
        });
```

and my Server side code is -

```
 //send message
    socket.on('send message', function (data) {
        io.sockets.in(socket.room).emit('new message', {msg: data, user: socket.username});
    });
```

I tried many ways but I am not getting the idea how to do that.

Please, some give some suggestion on this.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Can you please show some code?

Comment: @SmitRaval html code?

Comment: Both html and socket.

Comment: @SmitRaval Please check.

Comment: where are you appending sent message? I can't find a code for that.

Comment: Please check my client-side code.

Answer (score 0):

Well,
all you need to do i track who is 'this' user (You) and who is other users.
So, save your 'id', 'name' (name is bad idea) whatever you use to identify users.
Then, when rendering messages, add different html classes to these elements.

Example:

```
<div class="message other-user"> {message.text} </div>
<div class="message this-user"> {message.text} </div>
```

Then, just create classes in css

Example:

```
.message.other-user { text-align: left }
.message.this-user {text-align: right}
```

Comment: Thanx for your answer but I am not getting the idea how to differentiate both users.

Comment: Well, when you do the appending of the message (when you receive it ) you have data.text and data.user. Now, you should add something like data.userId (for example) for each message.  And for your user ("self") should store its own userId somewhere in browser ( for (bad) example window.myUserId, or in LocalStorage/SessionStorage of browser).  so whenever you receive a message from socket with data.userId ===  window.myUserId, then you put it right, otherwise left. Does it make sense?

Comment: yes, I understand but the problem is that for example (let the id of user1 = 1 and of user2 = 2 and the user2 join the room to the id=1 of user1 i.e 1, so when I am trying to send message to their particular id like to id=1 , then it is sending the message to both users because they both are connected to id=1. will you have suggestion for that ?

Comment: For simplicity, let's say there's only one room. Now, if I join the room with only you in it, and send a message, it sends to both users. which is fine. Only difference is that you will see (by userId) that the message is from me and display it left, and if you send the message, you will see that userId (of the message) is same to your userId and will display it right. in this way, both of us will have 2 message in chat dialog